# Why Twitter API requests user's permission each time?

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I'm using Twitter API with CodeBird (PHP).

Here is a quote from Twitter's docs:

> so for users already signed in to twitter.com who have authorized the application, no UI is shown - instead, they are automatically redirected back to the application.
>
> In the case where the user is already signed in to twitter.com and has granted access to the website, this redirect happens immediately.

https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/desktop-browser

Why this does not work for me? Twitter asks user's permission for each time.

My code for obtaining authorization URL:

```
    \Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey(
        $this->config['twitter']['consumer_key'],
        $this->config['twitter']['consumer_secret']
    );

    $cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();

    $reply = $cb->oauth_requestToken([
        'oauth_callback' => 'https://***/login/twitter'
    ]);

    $cb->setToken($reply->oauth_token, $reply->oauth_token_secret);

    $this->session->twitter_oauth_token = $reply->oauth_token;
    $this->session->twitter_oauth_token_secret = $reply->oauth_token_secret;
    $this->session->twitter_oauth_verify = true;

    return $this->redirect($cb->oauth_authorize());
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

**oauth_authorize** will always ask user for a permission.

**oauth_authenticate** will request it only once and will perform automatic redirect, if access already granted.